# Using external dependencies in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

If I am working on a C project that uses other libraries, what would be the best way to locate these libraries and their associated include directories on the host system? One way I could do this by having a library directory path and library include directory path variable for each library like this:

```
<LIBNAME>_DIR = /path/to/lib
<LIBNAME>_INC = /path/to/include

<LIBNAME2>_DIR = /path/to/lib2
<LIBNAME2>_INC = /path/to/include2

...
```

and then having the user pass substitute the path to the lib on their system for these variables like this

```
make <LIBNAME>_DIR=/path/to/lib ...
```

but this would become kind of a hassle once my project starts using more of these external dependencies.

Comment: Oi.  As much as I hate to mention it, look into `pkg-config`.  This is a non-trivial problem, and the absolute best solution is to install your libraries and headers in standard locations so that the problem goes away.  `pkg-config` is a terrible hack to solve this problem, which should be solved with proper control of your filesystem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, but I do not want to make any assumptions about where the user installs their libraries and headers.

Comment: And your reluctance to insist that the user follow normal procedures will cause you a great deal of headaches.  The proper solution for a user that insists on installing his/her tools in non-standard locations is to tell them to deal with their own mess. Barring that; look at `pkg-config`.  It is an attempt to deal with precisely the problem you are describing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell alright, thanks.

Comment: Among the common ways to approach this kind of problem is by using build-system creation tools such as the Autotools or CMake to create your build system for you, including bundled scripts and tools for locating libraries and affording builders the option to specify their locations.  But doing so is **much** more complicated than just relying on libraries to be installed in one of the conventional locations.